# With SQL JOIN, how to limit the results of one table to most recent record

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am attempting a select sql statement using join and am having trouble limiting the result set to what I desire.

Here are the two tables

ASSET

| ACCOUNT_ID | NAME | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99492 | 12204 | TRUE |
| 99492 | 12205 | TRUE |
| 99492 | 12206 | FALSE |
| 99492 | 12207 | TRUE |

DEVICE_STATE

| ACCOUNT_ID | ASSET_NAME | LANDMARK_NAME | EVENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99492 | 12204 | WAREHOUSE 1 | 2021-06-11 11:04:23 AM |
| 99492 | 12204 | WAREHOUSE 1 | 2021-06-11 10:54:38 AM |
| 99492 | 12204 | WAREHOUSE 1 | 2021-06-11 11:07:13 AM |
| 99492 | 12205 | WAREHOUSE 3 | 2021-06-11 09:08:27 AM |
| 99492 | 12205 | WAREHOUSE 3 | 2021-06-11 12:05:29 PM |
| 99492 | 12206 | WAREHOUSE 5 | 2021-06-11 08:23:56 PM |
| 99492 | 12207 | WAREHOUSE 9 | 2021-06-11 04:47:12 PM |

What I am trying to achieve is for each result in ASSET where ACTIVE=TRUE, I want the most recent EVENT_DATE from DEVICE_STATE.  In this sample data, the result would be

| ACCOUNT_ID | ASSET_NAME | LANDMARK_NAME | EVENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99492 | 12204 | WAREHOUSE 1 | 2021-06-11 11:07:13 AM |
| 99492 | 12205 | WAREHOUSE 3 | 2021-06-11 12:05:29 PM |
| 99492 | 12207 | WAREHOUSE 9 | 2021-06-11 04:47:12 PM |

I have searched many answers on here and tried several different queries - most recently this one

```
select
    A.NAME, d.LANDMARK_NAME, d.LANDMARK_ON_START
from ASSET a 
    JOIN  ( select d.*, ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY ASSET_NAME ORDER BY EVENT_DATE DESC) AS seqnum
            FROM DEVICE_STATE d 
        ) d ON a.ACCOUNT_ID = 99492 
            AND a.ACTIVE = 'TRUE' 
            AND d.ASSET_NAME = a.NAME 
            AND seqnum = 1
```

While this code does not throw any errors, it executes forever and ever, making me believe that it is not just selecting the most recent EVENT_DATE (there could be thousands and thousands for each ASSET_NAME) but rather trying to process all of them.

Is there a tweak on this code that would fix that issue or is there an entirely different approach to accomplish this?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r1.ACCOUNT_ID,r1.ASSET_NAME,r1.LANDMARK_NAME,MAX(r1.EVENT_DATE) AS  EVENT_DATE 
      FROM DEVICE_STATE r1 
      JOIN ASSET r2 ON t1.ASSET_NAME=r2.name 
      WHERE r2.active 
      GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID,ASSET_NAME,LANDMARK_NAME
```

assuming that ASSET.NAME field is Unique in ASSET table else you have to add ACCOUNT_ID in the JOIN.

Comment: Thanks for this.  ASSET.NAME could exist multiple times over different ACCOUNT_IDs, so I agree that should be added.  When I run this, I am getting the most recent EVENT_DATE for every existing LANDMARK_NAME for each ASSET_NAME.  I only want the most recent EVENT_DATE regardless of which LANDMARK_NAME it is related to, so how can we tweak this to result in only one row per ASSET_NAME?

Comment: > I only want the most recent EVENT_DATE regardless of which LANDMARK_NAME it is related to ...  you have to group only by ASSET_NAME but that means you cannot have what you wrote as final result, it's a pb of logic, how you have to define how to choose LANDMARK_NAME ... and I cannaot figure out ...